# How to sort HashMap based on Date?

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap, date-sorting

I trying to sort this HashMap based on date in keys

My Hash map:

`Map<Date, ArrayList> m = new HashMap<Date, ArrayList>();`

Comment: #winces# I'd be careful of attempting to use this in a multi-threaded environment, if you aren't using those `Date`s in an immutable fashion - calling any of that objects `get()` methods actually mutates the values it holds, so the actual value depends on the order of (not only) `set()`s _and_ `get()`s.  I'd rather trust the JodaTime library for this...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use a [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) instead of [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). As [`Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) already implements [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), it will be sorted automatically on insertion.

```
Map<Date, ArrayList> m = new TreeMap<Date, ArrayList>();
```

Alternatively, if you have an existing `HashMap` and want to create a `TreeMap` based on it, pass it to the constructor:

```
Map<Date, ArrayList> sortedMap = new TreeMap<Date, ArrayList>(m);
```

#### See also:

- [Java tutorials - Map implementations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/map.html)
- [Java tutorials - Object ordering](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html)

Comment: If I am implementing Sort on dates, the above method will sort them based on first day of the year. While I want a sort based on the current date, I will have to implement a comparator. Any heading?

Comment: @Pirate: It's sorted on timestamp (as available by `Date#getTime()`), not on first day of year. Even more, the `java.util.Date` doesn't have any concept like "first day of year". Your problem is caused elsewhere. Perhaps `Date` instances used as keys were created the wrong way via `java.util.Calendar` which indeed has a concept of "first day of year". Just press "Ask Question" button on right top along with an SSCCE in order to be able to get answers on that.

Comment: So you mean it is sorted based on the current date?

Comment: @Pirate: It's sorted on timestamp, not on first day of year as you implied. So it's not e.g. `1 Jan 2012, 1 Jan 2013, 2 Jan 2012, 2 Jan 2013`, but it's `1 Jan 2012, 2 Jan 2012, 1 Jan 2013, 2 Jan 2013`.

Comment: Means I do not have to implement a comparetor, however as these date values are stored as keys, do they need to be unique? I am about to find this all out, writing a SSCCE.

Comment: How to sort it in descending order?

Comment: @MrNarendra: just use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#reverseOrder--

Answer (score 0):

Use TreeMap instead of HashMap to store the data，it will be sorted automatically.

Comment: Welcome at Stack Overflow! Just curious, why are you repeating an already given answer? This isn't kind of a "discussion forum" where folks usually confirm the answer by repeating it more or something. Here on a Q&A site you just vote it up or post a better answer. See also http://stackoverflow.com/faq.

Comment: Yeah,I got it.I will do better.