# How to sort dates in Map<String, String> in java with other value

Tags: java, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sort a Map<Key, Value> on the values in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java)

I have a map in java with `Map<String, String>`.Map contaions `<Id, Date>`. i want to sort these map according to date. how can i do that? This is the map after print it

```
-------------------------------------
PTRRRRRR     08-20-2011
-------------------------------------
TESTDESC     08-01-2012
-------------------------------------
TESTMYO      12-29-2011
-------------------------------------
TESTTEST     08-01-2012
-------------------------------------
TESTPROL     08-01-2012
-------------------------------------
TESTPRO      08-01-2012
-------------------------------------
PNAMELQ      08-02-2012
-------------------------------------
TESTMYO      12-29-2011
------------------------------------
```

Comment: `TESTPRO` appears more than once, but keys have to be unique??

Comment: Are they actually `Date` objects or are they strings? Date strings in that format don't sort the way you want without effort.

Comment: Check this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298290/how-to-sort-hashmap-based-on-date

Comment: @Sajith It seems the dates are the values, not the keys, so your link would not apply.

Comment: If you want to sort by value then this would be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java

Comment: I want to know is their a way to sort dates in java

Comment: Since ```Date``` implements ```Comparable```, there is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html and notice, that there are differnt `Map` Implementations:

> The order of a map is defined as the order in which the iterators on the map's collection views return their elements. Some map implementations, like the TreeMap class, make specific guarantees as to their order; others, like the HashMap class, do not.

In http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html you'll find this definition:

> The map is sorted according to the natural ordering of its **keys**, or by a Comparator provided at map creation time, depending on which constructor is used.

Since you want to compare by value (`Map<String, Date>`), you need to implement a `Comparator` that compares by value (this is untested):

```
class ValueComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    Map<String, Date> map;
    public ValueComparator(Map<String, Date> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    public int compare(String a, String b) {
        return map.get(a).compareTo(map.get(b));
    }
}
```

(You may want to build the ValueComparator more generic.)

Finally construct the map with

```
Map<String, Date> sorted = new TreeMap<String, Date>(new ValueComparator(unsortedMap));
sorted.putAll(unsortedMap);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a custom Comparator like this.

```
String data = "PTRRRRRR     08-20-2011\n" +
        "TESTDESC     08-01-2012\n" +
        "TESTMYO      12-29-2011\n" +
        "TESTTEST     08-01-2012\n" +
        "TESTPROL     08-01-2012\n" +
        "TESTPRO      08-01-2012\n" +
        "TESTPRO      08-01-2012\n" +
        "PNAMELQ      08-02-2012\n" +
        "TESTMYO      12-29-2011\n";
Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
for (String line : data.split("\n")) {
    String[] keyValue = line.split(" +");
    map.put(keyValue[0], keyValue[1]);
}
Map.Entry<String, String>[] entries = map.entrySet().toArray(new Map.Entry[map.size()]);
Arrays.sort(entries, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, String>>() {
    SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");

    @Override
    public int compare(Map.Entry<String, String> o1, Map.Entry<String, String> o2) {
        try {
            return date.parse(o1.getValue()).compareTo(date.parse(o2.getValue());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
    }
});
for (Map.Entry entry : entries) {
    System.out.println(entry);
}
```

prints

```
PTRRRRRR=08-20-2011
TESTMYO=12-29-2011
TESTDESC=08-01-2012
TESTTEST=08-01-2012
TESTPROL=08-01-2012
TESTPRO=08-01-2012
PNAMELQ=08-02-2012
```

Comment: using Collections#sort on Map#entrySet would be faster than copying data to an array and using Arrays#sort.

Comment: Good answer. Really makes one appreciate the beauty of `map.OrderBy(x => DateTime.Parse(x.Value))` though!

Comment: We'll have to wait for Java 8 for that. But it will come...

Comment: @coding.mof It would be faster, except you can't do that. ;) Collections.sort requires a List.

Comment: Good point. ;) Never realized that.